# Flask-SQLAlchemy - adding a new column to a query to pass to a template

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For a simple library app in Flask with Flask-SQLAlchemy, I have a Book table and a Checkout table:

```
class Checkout(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    checkout_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    return_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'))
    book = db.relationship('Book',
        backref=db.backref('checkout', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Checkout Book ID=%r from %s to %s>' % (self.book.id, self.checkout_date, self.return_date)
```

I want to keep all checkout records, and I figure the normalized way to do this is to use `Checkout.return_date` to determine if the book is returned or not. If the return date of **any** associated Checkout record is null, the Book is still checked out and if it has no null records, the book is "available". (Really it should never have two null return_dates)

The SQL for this view would be:

```
select book.*, min(checkout.return_date is not null) as available 
from book 
left join checkout 
on book.id = checkout.book_id
group by book.id;
```

I can't figure out how to do this in SQLAlchemy without copping out and using a raw SQL string:

```
db.session.query(Book).from_statement('select book.*, min(checkout.return_date is not null) as available from book left join checkout on book.id = checkout.book_id group by book.id').all()
```

But I can't access `spam_book.available`: I get the error `'Book' object has no attribute 'available'`

Is there a way to add a dynamic, temporary attribute on to a Book to pass to the template? Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

**My end goal is to be able to do `{% if book.available %}` for each book, in the template.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I understand your `Book` to `Checkout` relationship is OneToMany and you are doing:

- Only one book can be checked out for one record
- You library could have more than one copies of one book
- Different copies of one book will have different and unique `book_id`

Try to add a method for your `Book` model.

```
class Book(db.Model):
    # ...something you already have

    def is_available(self):
        return not self.checkout.filter(Checkout.return_date.isnot(None)).scalar()
```

In the template, just use:

```
{% if book.is_available %}
```

should do the trick.

This is not tested as I don't have SQLAlchemy at hand. Please tell me if it does not work.